# How can I install Photoshop CS5?

Tags: wine, photoshop

I copied all of the files like in [this](http://www.unixmen.com/linux-tutorials/linux-distributions/linux-distributions4-ubuntu/1681-how-to-install-photoshop-in-ubuntu-and-linuxmint) tutorial, but I have no luck launching PS. I also tried running the installer with WINE, but needed AIR and it wouldn't connect to the adobe servers.

Also, I (think I) removed all of the libraries I installed with winetricks (except for the VC++ ones) and deleted the files I copied from my Windows machine. This is all perfectly safe, right?

Comment: Have you doe what it says here? :http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=20158

Comment: maybe you don't want to do this but you can install windows under Virtualbox and there install PS.

Comment: Oh, I see, I copied the 64-bit program files. I'll follow the HOWTO on WineHQ, but why is there a `rm -rf ~/.wine` command?

Comment: Did you manage to install it successfully? If so which steps did you follow?

Answer (score 3):

Install it through Playonlinux but not as effective as in Windows. Open your terminal and type: `sudo apt-get install playonlinux` and ENTER. Open Playonlinux from you 'Dash Home' and look for Photoshop cs5 or other version you are willing to install to your system and follow instruction on screen.After that go back to your 'Dash Home', click on Photoshop to run it.

I think Playonlinux has even a patch should in case the program did not run perfectly. It does it better than the others.

Comment: Thanks, but PlayOnLinux only has CS4.

Answer (score 2):

Photoshop 5 through CS2 and CS4 install and work pretty well on wine. Photoshop CS3 has [some issues](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=6584) but most things work.

Here are some tips you'll need to run Photoshop successfully:

1). You shouldn't have to copy Photoshop from Windows; just install it under Wine by running its Setup.exe. (To run a .exe under wine, you have to doubleclick it, right click and choose "Run with Wine", or run it from the commandline using the 'wine' command, depending on how your Linux distribution integrates Wine.)

2).Never use a cracked version of Photoshop (this isn't a moralizing thing: the cracks themselves don't work reliably in Wine).

3).Never run Wine as root.

4).Use a recent version of Wine (1.1.6 or later).

5).When installing Photoshop CS2 trial, be sure to enter your name and organization. If you don't, Photoshop's installer gives a confusing error dialog.

6).Before installing Photoshop CS or CS2, do `wget http://kegel.com/wine/winetricks; sh winetricks corefonts vcrun6`

```
 if the above line produces the error *cabextract: command not found* type in `sudo apt-get install cabextract` (Ubuntu/Debian), run, and run the above line again.
```

7).Before installing Photoshop CS3, do `wget http://kegel.com/wine/winetricks; sh winetricks gecko gdiplus` (or follow these instructions).
When installing Photoshop CS4, follow these instructions.

The Clone tool uses the ALT key in a way that conflicts with many window managers. Here's how to fix that:

Ubuntu or Fedora: Go to *System → Preferences → Windows, and under Movement Key, pick "Super" instead of "Alt"*.

If you have a keyboard with the AltGr key (not many US keyboards have this): duplicating Marquee selections with AltGr+Arrows didn't work, you have to use Ctrl+Alt+Arrows instead
compiz plugins might also steal important keystrokes (Ctrl+Arrows, Shift+Arrows, Shift+Ctrl+Arrows, Ctrl+Alt+Arrows) used by Photoshop for moving, cuting und duplicating Marquee selections. For instance, see RotateCube. You might need to disable Compiz or those plugins to use Photoshop properly.
Some UI elements might use a too-small font. In CS2, you can fix this with Edit / Preferences / General, and change UI Font Size from Small to Medium

Comment: What about CS5? That's what I have a license for...

Comment: Photoshop CS5 also works in Ubuntu 11.10 (in my experience) under wine, even though i have some issues of unexpected quits using fonts in CS5.